# Show the Redux state React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I don't know why my `console.log(el)` display elements of `filters` object like array - just names as string type.

mapReducer.js

```
const initState = {
    filters: {
        basen: {
            active: true,
            name: 'BASEN'
        },
        koszykowka: {
            active: true,
            name: 'KOSZYKÓWKA'
        },
        pilka_nozna: {
            active: true,
            name: 'PIŁKA NOŻNA'
        },
        pilka_reczna: {
            active: true,
            name: 'PIŁKA RĘCZNA'
        },
        siatkowka: {
            active: true,
            name: 'SIATKÓWKA'
        },
        tenis: {
            active: true,
            name: 'TENIS'
        }
    }
}
```

objectFilters.js

```
{Object.keys(this.props.filters).map((el, i) => {
                console.log(el)
                return(
                    <ObjectFiltersElement 
                        key={i} 
                        name={el.name} 
                        active={el.active} 
                        changeFilterHandler={(el) => (this.changeFilterHandler(el))}
                        />
                )
            })}
```

objectFiltersElement.js

```
<div className={elementStyle} onClick={() => props.changeFilterHandler(props.name)}>
    {props.name}
</div>
```

And `console.log(el)` give me this:
[image]

Elements of `filters` not as objects but as strings.

When I am tring get to active or name of object I got undefinded.

```
    console.log("THIS.PROPS.FILTERS", this.props.filters)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `.map` on `Object.keys(this.props.filters)` which is an `Array` of object key names like - `['basen', 'koszykowka', 'pilka_nozna' ....]`.

In your `console.log(el)` you can see its `basen` (lowercase). You need to modify the data to consume it in you `.map()` method. That is the reason you are getting `undefined` when trying to get access to `active` or `name`.

I think this code will work for you -

`Object.keys(this.props.filters).map(x => this.props.filters[x]).map((el, i) => {...}`

Example Code For creating an Array from Object -

```js
var filter = {
        basen: {
            active: true,
            name: 'BASEN'
        },
        koszykowka: {
            active: true,
            name: 'KOSZYKÓWKA'
        },
        pilka_nozna: {
            active: true,
            name: 'PIŁKA NOŻNA'
        },
        pilka_reczna: {
            active: true,
            name: 'PIŁKA RĘCZNA'
        },
        siatkowka: {
            active: true,
            name: 'SIATKÓWKA'
        },
        tenis: {
            active: true,
            name: 'TENIS'
        }
    };


var newFilter = Object.keys(filter).map(x => filter[x])

console.log(newFilter)
```

Second Approach -

```
const { filters } = this.props;
{Object.keys(filters).map((el, i) => {
                console.log(el)
                return(
                    <ObjectFiltersElement 
                        key={i} 
                        name={filters[el].name} 
                        active={filters[el].active} 
                        changeFilterHandler={(el) => (this.changeFilterHandler(el))}
                        />
                )
            })}
```

Comment: OK, I understand where is the problem, but honestly I have no idea how should i modify this data..

Comment: Can i somehow fix it without changes in my Redux state ?

Comment: @poldeeek Can u please `console.log(this.props.filters)`. I need to see how and in what format data is coming

Comment: I added it at the end of question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213275/discussion-between-poldeeek-and-swapnesh).